# Selenium Python Firefox Xvfb Browser Creation / Disk Space Issues

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, xvfb

Been trying to run a test using Selenium, Python, Firefox, and Xvfb. I constantly keep having issues with the browser not being able to create and running out of disk space after a few hours of running the test. Everywhere I read it says to use browser.quit() to release the tmp, but still running into disk space issues. Then on top of that, had to stick the browser creation into a while loop, just to get it to create every time. After every link the test visits, I have it quit the browser and open a new one. If anyone has any ideas why I am running into these issues I would really appreciate it.

```
import time
import re

from selenium import webdriver
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from decimal import Decimal

display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()

links = tuple(open('links.txt'))

for link in links:
  #Try to create browser
  while True:
    try:
      browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    except Exception:
      time.sleep(1)
    else:
      break
  #Navigate to link
  try:
    browser.get(link)
  except Exception:
    time.sleep(1)
  else:
    #Switch to first iframe
    try:
      ele = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/iframe')                     
      browser.switch_to_frame(ele)
    except Exception:
      time.sleep(1)
    else:
      time.sleep(1)
      #Switch to second iframe
      try:
        ele = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/iframe[1]')
        browser.switch_to_frame(ele)
      except Exception:
        time.sleep(1)
      else:
        time.sleep(1)
        #Wait for timer, if one is found
        while True:
          try:
            wait = browser.find_element_by_id('one')
            wait = wait.text
            wait = re.sub("\D", "", wait)
            wait = Decimal(timer)
          except Exception:
            break
          else:
            if wait == 0:
              break
            else:
              time.sleep(1)
        #Click second element
        try:
          ele = browser.find_element_by_id('two')
          ele.click()
        except Exception:
          time.sleep(1)
        else:
          time.sleep(1)
  #Quit browser if one exist
  try:
    browser.quit()
  except Exception:
    time.sleep(1)
  else:
    time.sleep(1)
```